# Why can't I turn the volume all the way down during calls?

Tags: calls, volume

I asked this because I have searched way too long and all the results I'm getting is why is your phone silent during calls. I can't turn the volume silent during calls, like my zoom meeting. Why?

Comment: I may misunderstand the statement, but I assume by "I can't turn the volume silent during calls, like my zoom meeting", you meant "I can silent Zoom meeting, but not phone call", not "I cannot silent both phone calls and Zoom meeting"?

Comment: No, I meant that I cannot silent both phone calls and Zoom meetings

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [How do I completely mute the sound in phone calls?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234807/44325)

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer that took me too long to find.

Settings > Accessibility > Hearing Enhancements > Mute all sounds

Comment: Looks like this is Samsung's customization. Google Pixel doesn't have Hearing Enhancements in Accessibility. Otherwise, could you mention the device model and Android version for completeness?